# Create a common interface between JDBC and JsonDatabase

Tags: java, json, oracle, jdbc

I have a conceptual question. I have an application that uses JDBC for communication with an Oracle database. I would like to introduce a custom JSON database mock for local application development.

The JDBC query returns a ResultSet 
The Json query returns a JsonArray

Could you give me a hint how to make a common interface between those two returned types.

For example in order to hydrate the result the JsonArray is converted to JsonObject that have methods like getString getInt etc. Those methods are the same in ResultSet.

One of the solution that I am looking is to implement the ResultSet interface in JsonArray class but for this scenario I do not need those SQL related methods.

I need something like a GenericResultSet return type that could be pass to a factory that expect Resultset and a factory that expects a JsonArray / JsonObject.

Comment: Not only ResultSet interface but also you will need to implement Connection and Statement interfaces to accomplish that.  Actually, you will need a wrapper of your db connection to provide a mechanism to create statements and so on.

Comment: Will you need to create a connection and prepared statements?

Comment: I have two implementation of Database abstraction one for JDBC and one for JSONDb the first one have connection and the second one does not.
The prepared statments are going to be executed in JDBC implementation but the JSON will not have any it is going to return a result set directly

Comment: You should hide JDBC and instead use a DAO or something that returns common objects. The fact your current code seems to return `ResultSet` indicates you are either leaking connection objects or are otherwise doing weird things with the connection lifetime.